# Building an Android application with Buildozer fails with a non-obvious error log

Tags: python, buildozer

When I generate an Android application with kivy-buildozer, the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 1612:                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp --install-lib=.

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 668, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 844, in build_arch
    self.install_python_package(arch)
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 863, in install_python_package
    _env=hpenv, *self.setup_extra_args)
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/winicios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp --install-lib=.

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
    from setuptools import windows_support
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools-python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/winicios/estudos/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I researched how to solve and found nothing related about this error.

Comment: Possibly worth looking at -- https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/815

Comment: Is this the questions from the p4a Common Errors, ["ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘_ctypes’"](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting/#modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ctypes)?